# How to build a PDA that accepts strings which have odd numbers of a and even numbers of b and has only 2 states?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

How can i draw a PDA which has **only 2** states and accepts strings which have odd number of a and even number of b?

the alphabet is {a,b}, and the PDA has to be only 2 states?

Comment: You can do it with 2 parallel DFAs each with 2 states. Make the top of the stack represent one of the DFAs and the states of the PDA the other.

Comment: Wow thats actually very smart, thanks for the answer, also one last question, can we have something inside our "stack" in the initial state before we get any input ? or the stack has to be always empty at the beginning ? @ratchet freak

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to  remind you that in  fact for *every* context-free grammar there exists an equivalent PDA that has only a *single* state using acceptance by *empty stack*. If we need to use PDA acceptance by *final state* then *two states* are required as we need a working state and a separate accepting state.

The single state construction is given on [wikipedia's page for PDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#PDA_and_context-free_languages) and is called the expand-match construction for "parsing" context-free languages. The state here is called $1$.

1. $(1,\varepsilon ,A,1,\alpha )$ for each rule $\displaystyle A\to
       \alpha $   (expand)
2. $\displaystyle (1,a,a,1,\varepsilon )$ for each
   terminal symbol $a$ (match)

Note this uses the classical definition of PDA where the automaton starts with a fixed single element on its stack. A certain textbook has decided to change this basic definition and starts with the empty stack, where an extra state is needed to push the initial stack symbol. (horrible, this textbook is actually quite common and continues to spoil young kids).

when restricted to FSA the construction is actually quite simple. The PDA keeps the state on the stack as its only element. Accepting states of the FSA may be popped from the PDA so the PDA can accept (by empty stack) whenever the FSA can accept.